# Troubleshooting endless provisioning in Azure after custom image deployment

Tags: azure, opensuse

I have *tried* to create a custom Linux VM image based on openSuse 12.2 with [Suse Studio](https://www.susestudio.com). I have used Studio's *upload to Azure* feature to deploy the image to my BLOB container. I have made sure I installed `WALinuxAgent` package.

I then deployed the whole thing to Azure using Studio's uploader and created a VM with the newly uploaded image. The machine is still under `provisioning` status. I left it for a few minutes then tried to start the machine, no result.

DNS is reachable but the VM won't respond to port 22. It's still a few hours that the machine is under `provisioning` status.

How can I let a simple Suse image run on Azure before customizing it with my software?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a custom VM template.  Mine's still not working despite the recommendation to remove all snapshots related to the vhd.  Just saying in case that may be your problem ... don't know.